# How to use libpcap to receive ethernet frame with poll()

Tags: c, linux, libpcap

I have a project which uses poll() to handle the network communication including TCP and Ethernet. Poll is used to support TCP or UDP conneciton. Recenctly I want to use libpcap to receive frames and integrate libpcap into this code with poll().

The poll() needs to know the file descriptor, but the pcap does not returns the file descriptor. How to manage pcap with poll() system.

The project is in C code on linux. The reason I do not want to use raw socket is for the pcap's high efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If, on a UN*X, you have a `pcap_t *` from a call such as `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()`, you can get a file descriptor to hand to `poll()` or `select()` or something such as that by calling `pcap_get_selectable_fd()`.  Note that it can return -1, which means that `select()`/`poll()`/etc. aren't supported on that particular device on the OS version you're using.  (The OS version shouldn't matter for Linux, but it might matter for some BSDs.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Linux manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_get_selectable_fd). You can use `pcap_get_selectable_fd`. But it's not reliable on most BSDs. `Some network devices opened with pcap_create() and pcap_activate(), or with pcap_open_live(), do not support select() or poll() (for example, regular network devices on FreeBSD 4.3 and 4.4, and Endace DAG devices), so -1 is returned for those devices.`  Refer to manual for more details.